# How can I pass an anonymous function to a Celery task? (Or accomplish my goal some other way?)

Tags: python, serialization, celery, anonymous-function

I have a file-downloading Celery task.  More than one method in my main application is going to use this task and I'm trying to abstract it so the same task can be used for different purposes.  At one point in my task I had

```
 if r.ok:
        results = [result for result in r.json()['ResultSet']['Result']
                   if all([condition(result) for condition in conditions])]
```

And I thought I was going to be clever and pass it

```
conditions=[lambda result: 'json' not in result['Name']]
```

Only I can't because that gets me an error telling me that objects of type function are not serializable.

For now, I have changed the line in the task to:

```
 if r.ok:
        results = [result for result in r.json()['ResultSet']['Result']
                   if all([excluded not in result[attr] for attr, excluded in exclusions.items()])]
```

And I pass it `exclusions={'Name':'json'}`.

It's just going to be a bummer if I start to want to exclude files for other reasons than that some aspect of the response doesn't have a particular text string in it.  I wondered if anyone had any ideas for a serializable version of my highly generalized conditions parameter.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The only way to accomplish this is to pass the name of the function you want to run as a string, and have a predefined set of functions existing on your workers so they know what to run. You are asking too much of a distributed system.

Comment: I dunno, this suggestion works fine, so in another sense I'm not asking too much!